# Workforce Management Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, resources, scheduling, modeling

This may be a little or over complicated situation. I have been asked to create a resource model for a content development organization.The org develops e-learning, multimedia content and also delivers training. So i need to create different models for all 3. 
I did research a bit and found info on erlang c algorithm and also few white papers giving information. I am looking for some guidance on how to go about doing this. All the help with be appreciated

Comment: [Smalltalk 80 The Language and its Implementation](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/BlueBook/Bluebook.pdf). Take a look at Chapter 24.

Comment: Thanks but the book is focussed around VM resources. I need to build a model for the developers & trainers

Comment: Chapter 24 is about how to model resources in general under the realm of simulation systems. That's why I pointed it out.

Comment: Hey, the link doesnt work in my country..its blocked for some reasons